# Beforestep annotation does not take an argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-boot

I'm a little bit confused on the usage of @Beforestep in an ItemReader in Spring Batch.

When I use

```
public class MyItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {

    long teller = 0L;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution se) {
    }

    @Override
    public String read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

        if(teller == 11)
        return null;

        return String.valueOf(++teller);
    }
}
```

I do get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The method [beforeStep] on target class [MyItemReader] is incompatible with the signature [(StepExecution)] expected for the annotation [BeforeStep].
```

This situation does not cause an exception:

```
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
    }
```

However, the first situation is described in the documentation.

What is expected? And how do I send the SendExecution object to the object when I cannot add it to the argument list?

I'm using spring-boot-starter-batch-1.1.6.RELEASE

Comment: Did you set your bean as `scope="step"` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Now I tried to do so, but still the same error.

Comment: You could use an xml like this .. `<bean id="myItemReader" class="your.package.MyItemReader" scope="step"/>`. Without scope step you defining a singleton bean.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your job's configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. There are 2 StepExecution classes: `org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution` and `javax.batch.runtime.StepExecution` Use the first one, not the second one (like I did).